# Should I commit environment.ts file containing firestore initialization config

Tags: git, firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore

Should the following be pushed to git:

```
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "secret_api_key",
    authDomain: "nicoavila-allpurpose.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://nicoavila-allpurpose.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "nicoavila-allpurpose",
    storageBucket: "nicoavila-allpurpose.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "6870000001"
  }
};
```

If not, how could I hide it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37482366/6309 should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source code is open source, you probably should NOT check it in.  The issue is not so much safety as it is confusion from others who use your source code.  Every instance of your app should be running in a different project so they don't overwrite each others' data.

If your source is NOT open source, and all of your coworkers are using the same project to collaborate, then it's not a problem.  But everyone sharing a project is not a great idea since all of their changes to the project might still conflict with each other.

In general, it's better not to share your project configuration unless everyone needs to use it.